# Is there a Swift bridge for Python?

Tags: swift, python-3.x, applescript, translate, bridge

I developed a script to set attributes for my iTunes music library on my Mac using an Apple Script bridge called [AppScript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/). `AppScript` Allowed me to write my code in native Python without having to learn Apple Script. AppSript would translate my native Python to Apple Script. Since Apple Script has been replaced with `Swift` I am wondering if there is a similar bridge for Swift. I have done my research, but no luck. Additionally if there is, can you provide an example of how to control iTunes(now Music) with said library? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you get the idea that Swift has replaced AppleScript? They are actually quite different , one is a programming language the other a scripting language

Comment: AppleScript isn’t replaced, though it’s definitely dead in the water. I wrote [SwiftAutomation](https://bitbucket.org/hhas/swiftae/) a few years back, but it’s the same deal as appscript: no maintenance, no support. Honestly, you’re best just to [call into AppleScript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html) via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift is designed to use MacOS's programming APIs: **AppKit, Quartz, CoreFoundation, NSObject**, etc, rather than the higher level OSAX event-driven elements (**open, print, close, document, window,** etc) used in AppleScript.

The system-bundled python (2.7) comes with pyObjC, which allows python to use the same programming APIs that Swift does, e.g. "writing apps". PyObjC also contains a Scripting Bridge to the AppleScript events and objects. The [canonical example code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Articles/UsingScriptingBridge.html) does use iTunes:

```
from Foundation import *
from ScriptingBridge import *
iTunes = SBApplication.applicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.iTunes")
print iTunes.currentTrack().name()
```

*(Obvs, this is python2 and you need to put brackets round the print command. Also, personally, I wouldn't `import *` everything, as it's very slow.)*

Here are some other methods/attributes based on the Script Dictionary:

```
iTunes.nextTrack()
iTunes.previousTrack()
iTunes.playpause()
iTunes.fastForward()
iTunes.setShuffleEnabled_(False)
iTunes.currentPlaylist().playOnce_(False)
```

The system-bundled version of pyObjC is very old, but the library itself is still being developed. If you're using python3, then you should install the [latest version](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/) of pyObjC.

FWIW, you can actually run uncompiled Swift as a 'script' in the shell.

Comment: Thank you! This helps greatly! 

Where do I get the full syntax guide for iTunes/Music?

Comment: That's where it gets difficult. You'll likely have to look at iTunes's AppleScript Dictionary, and try stuff. You could also try the utilities here, but they're mostly for classes, not instances. https://pyobjc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/module-objc.html#accessing-classes-and-protocols

Comment: I'll add some examples to the answer.